# Blog with images interspersed throughout the post

Tags: php, mysql, blogs

Alright, been banging my head against this problem for a little while and can't seem to get what I am looking for on Google or anywhere else.  I have built a CMS blog using PHP and MySQL.  It works great.  I have a table that holds the blog information (title, author, date, and the post).  In my index.php I hit it like this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT posts.ID as 'ID' ,
    posts.author as 'author' ,
    posts.title as 'title' ,
    posts.category as 'category',
    posts.date as 'date', 
    LEFT(posts.post, 312) as 'post'
    FROM posts
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 3";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

Then I roll them onto the screen via:

```
    echo $row['ID'];
    echo $row['title'], etc., etc.
```

I also have a table that holds some image information - just the size, filename, etc.

In the 'posts' table, the actual posts are written in a text field.  I would really like to put some place holders in the text for images - you know, to make the blog posts look better, some interspersed images that relate to the content.  I can't seem to get it to work right though. I tried to pull it off like this:

```
    $sql2 = "select * from images, posts where posts.ID = images.image_post";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());

    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {
    echo "<div class=\"picture\">";
    echo "<p>";
    // Note that we are building our src string using the filename from the database
    echo "<img src=\"images/" . $row2['image_url'] . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";
    echo "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    }
```

Then I echo the post.  So the pictures show up, but all of the pictures in the folder show in every post.  I think it is because it is a while loop within a while loop - I am fairly sure that might tear a hole in the universe.

All I want is the pictures to show where I mark them in the text of the post.

Can anyone help me understand how to match the "marker" I put in the text field of the posts table to the image in the images table?  I keep looking online but everyone seems to use different ideas - str_replace, preg_match, preg_replace; and I can't seem to wrap my head around any of them.

So, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're trying to get out of $sql2. Are you trying to get only images that are marked as belonging to the current post? Then you need something like (you're missing the AND clause):

```
$sql2 = "select * from images, posts where posts.ID = images.image_post 
           AND posts.ID = ".$row['ID'];
```

After that, you need a way to put the image where you want in the post, not just at the end, I would imagine. Maybe you can have some kind of tag in the text of the post, and do a string replacement on that.

So you could have something in your text that looks like `[imageID:2837]`, then in your loop up above, you would change your code to pull the imageID's out with a regex, and do (for instance).

```
$sql2 = "select * from images where images.ID = ".$imageId
```

Comment: I am only trying to get the images marked as belonging to the current post.  So, your help with the $sql2 was perfect.  I am not sure I understand how to change the tag in the text with a regex.  How do I go about implementing that?  I am going to have to learn some more, I have never even heard of a regex. :o

Comment: Check out [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). You're going to do something like (totally untested) `$subject = $row['text'];
$pattern = '/\[imageID:(\d)\]/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);` then print out $matches. You should have the image ID in there, and then you can get that specific image from the database by ID.